# request send get error: [CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a83e00

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

I want to check the app version from apple so I send request like below

```
- (void)connectToCheckVersion{
NSString *url = @"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=466424846";
TTURLRequest *_request = [TTURLRequest requestWithURL:url delegate:self];
_request.httpMethod = @"GET";
_request.cachePolicy = TTURLRequestCachePolicyNone;
_request.shouldHandleCookies = NO;
TTURLJSONResponse* response = [[TTURLJSONResponse alloc] init];
_request.response = response;
TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(response); 
[_request send];
}


- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
    TTURLJSONResponse* response = request.response;
    NSDictionary* json = response.rootObject;

    NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
    NSString *version;
    for (NSDictionary *rawResult in results) {

        version = [rawResult objectForKey:@"version"];
    }
    NSString *currentVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    if (version != nil && currentVersion != nil && ![version isEqualToString:currentVersion]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"info" 
                                                        message:@"newer version" 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }

}
```

and after [_request send]; will get [CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a83e00. I checked all Strings in this method seems they are ok, and I can still get correct response from remote.

If I comment out this connectToCheckVersion method then no any problem. 
Any diea?

Comment: 2 suggestions here. 
- You're passing a string in **requestWithURL**. Usually it is [urlWithString:yourURLString];
- Don't autorelease **response**. Assign it to _request and then release it.

Comment: k, I updated code as above still not work, same issue...

Comment: the thing is I can get correct response from remote.

Comment: Is it possible that the point is I require the URL http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=466424846, the response lack some necessary info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should retain the **_request** variable and save it as a member.
Because it will **autorelease** after the function is returned.

You have to release it after the request is successed or failed.

Thank you.